# What dictates whether a probability distribution is assigned a name?

Tags: probability, soft-question, math-history

I'm curious as to how a probability distribution makes the transformation from an unlabeled function to a named and parameterized distribution (e.g., normal, binomial, Poisson, etc.)?

Is there a committee who decides which distributions are inducted into the royal family of named distributions? Or is it a slow process of repeated appearance, and established practical utility, that enables this transformation?

Comment: When a mathematical object is named after a person, typically that person is the first to have investigated that object thoroughly in a publication (without giving it a special name). If it is important, it will get cited by later authors repeatedly, perhaps first as "(object) described by (person) in (publication)" and after some time as "(person) (object)". -- This explains Poisson distribution, Bernoulli distribution, Laplace experiment, etc.; "binomial" comes form its relations to binoms; "normal" is a bit differrnt, being a special case of Gaussian, but still named by the same process

Comment: Like anything, we name probability measures for several reasons. The main reasons: (1):To easily reference, if we are going to be discussing them more than a little. (2) To honor the person who first discussed it or otherwise made it prominent. There are other reasons, but the main functional one is (1).

Comment: Presumably the ones we most want to talk about are also in some way important or common.